Code refuses to continue after injecting website with script -Selenium
So this is my code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

script = """
(() => {
    let clickCount = 0;  // Track total clicks
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        const buyButton = document.getElementById('TheBuyButton');
        const winningsElement = document.getElementById('numWinnings8');

        buyButton.click();
        clickCount++;

        // Check the winnings value
        const reward = winningsElement.innerText;
        console.log(`Click #${clickCount}: Winnings = ${reward}`);
        
        // Stop if it changes to "1" (indicating a win)
        if (reward === "1") {
            clearInterval(interval);
            document.body.setAttribute("data-status", "won");
            console.log(`Win detected after ${clickCount} clicks!`);
        }
    }, 0);  // 0ms delay for speed
})();
"""
clickslist = []
for i in range(2):
    options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless") 
    options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
    browser = webdriver.Edge(options=options)

    browser.get("https://www.skrabejulekalender-simulator.dk/game.php")

    for j in range(2):
        element = browser.find_element(By.ID, "menuButton")
        element.click()
    
    print("Im here")
    browser.execute_script(script)
    print("Im here now")

    while True:
        status = browser.execute_script("return document.body.getAttribute('data-status');")
        clicksCheck = browser.execute_script("return document.getElementById('numCalenders').innerText;")

        if status == "won":
            print("Win detected! Exiting loop.")
            clicks = browser.execute_script("return document.getElementById('numCalenders').innerText;")
            clickslist.append(clicks)
            break
        time.sleep(2)
        print(f"number of clicks: {clicksCheck}")
        

    browser.save_screenshot(f"Screenshot_{i}.png")
    print("Screenshot saved.")
    browser.quit()

k = " stk."

newList = [int(ele.replace(k,'')) for ele in clickslist]
print(newList)
print(f"average clicks till win: {sum(newList)/len(newList)}")

I've been trying for the past hour to make this work, but it just doesn't seem to go past: "browser.execute_script(script)". I'm running it on a Danish scratch card simulator. I want to see how many "scratch cards" it takes to get the 1 million reward. Thing is, the likelihood of getting a 1 million scratch card is so low that it takes a long time. Due to that Selenium ends up timing out, and I get a timeout error. How can I avoid this?
I tried polling, so Selenium shouldn't be "connected" to the server browser and it should be running independently and then Selenium will do some calls here and there (every 2 seconds) to check if it got a 1 million scratch card. Thing is even when I get the error, the website still runs the script, so it is independent of Selenium. The script also makes it stop, which works too.
Problem is that I need to do it for a long time with the 1 million scratch card, and I need to get past "browser.execute_script(script)" so I can actually get the amount of clicks, and append it to the clickslist and eventually see what I get.
When I run the program for a more common reward, it does go past the "browser.execute_script(script)". I'm doing something wrong, but I can't see it or maybe Selenium isn't the right module for me

without any waiting in that script it won't produce accurate results.  You are generating a click there and the web site will take some amount of time to respond to that.  You should probably move all that logic into Selenium and use proper webdriverwaits with explicit conditions.
